# How to send dynamic key and value both in jQuery Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dynamic

I want to send both the key and value to be dynamic(and the key is dynamic like coming from user input). Then how to send the request.
I want something like this:

```
var requestString;

if(something)
   requestString = "something";
else
   requestString= "else";

    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: handlerUrl,
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {
                            requestString: request.term
                        }
                    });
```

Here requestString is a variable and dynamically set. But for current code. the key is itself becoming "requestString" which was ought to be dynamic. How to do this?

Comment: you can try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114057/how-to-use-dynamic-data-name-with-jquery-post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
jQuery.ajax({
           url: handlerUrl,
           dataType: "json",
           data: requestString + '=' + request.term
      });
```

Comment: Thanks for the generic answer!!

Comment: Had to log in especially just to upvote this answer! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

create an object, push the dynamically generated key and value to it.. and pass that object as data in ajax..

try this

```
var requestString ;
 .....
dataString={};
dataString[requestString]=request.term

jQuery.ajax({
               url: handlerUrl,
               dataType: "json",
               data: dataString
          });
```